# Jquery multiply and add span and dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to compute the **total price** of items in a cart in Javascript. This is by multiplying the **quantity** by the **unit price** and then getting the grand total. 
The cart is populated by a PHP **while loop** so I am using class names.
The quantity field is a **dropdown/select** and the price field is a **span**.

```js
function sum() {

  var sum = 0;
  var q = 0;
  var s = 0;

  $('.itPrice,.qtys').each(function() {
    q = $('.qtys').text() || 0; //quantity
    s = $('.itPrice').text() || 0; //unit price
    sum = sum + (q * s);
  });

  //display total
  $("#sumT").text(sum);

}
```

```html
<!-- inside PHP while loop -->

<label>Price: </label>
<span class="itPrice"><b>'.$row["price"].'</b></span>

<label>Quantity: </label>
<Select id="qty" name="qty" class="qtys">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</Select>

<span id="sumT" name="sumT">*sum goes here*</span>
```

The output is **NaN** (Not a Number). Where am I going wrong? There is also a problem with the HTML select, it's not picking the selected option, only working with option '1'.

Comment: `$('.qtys').text()` and `$('.itPrice').text()` returns a string and not a Number. You can convert to Number like this: `parseInt($('.qtys').text())`. For price you want to `parseFloat`

Comment: Do each `itPrice` and `qty` pair have a shared parent that separates them from other pairs?  Also if these pairs are being repeated, take the id off the `qty`

Comment: A `select` element requires that you access is value, not its text. You also need to operate on individual prices paired with individual quantities. And you didn't give any valid data for the price, so we don't know if it's actually convertible to a number.

Comment: Using `value` instead of `text` for the `select` field returns an `Uncaught TypeError` in the browser console. How do I achieve pairing? Is it by using a single class for both fields? @Crazy Train

Comment: @Taplar How do I create a shared parent and refer to the children elements?

Comment: If you want to create a shared parent and do not want to impose any unwanted styling because of it, you could surround then with a span with a class on it.  Then you can just loop over the spans, and find the nested elements in them.

Comment: The `value` of a form input is accessed by the `.value` property. If you want to bog things down with jQuery, then you use their `.val()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select both related elements, as two collections of object, an iterate one collection (while using the array index to refer to the other); that way you can get the quantity and the price.

To get a `select` selected element, use jquery `val()` function instead of `text()`;

As a side note, you should not use duplicate id's or names for inputs in yout html. If you want an input with the same name, you can use `qty[]` for example.

```js
function sum() {

  var sum = 0, // Total sum
    it = $('.itPrice'), // All the .itPrice elements
    qty = $('.qtys'); // All the .qtys elements
  
  // For each .itPrice element
  it.each(function(i, e) {
    
    var current = $(this), // Gets the current .itPrice element
      related = $(qty[i]); // Get the related .qtys element, by array index
    
    // Sum
    sum += Number(current.find('b').text()) * related.val();
    
  });

  // return total
  return sum;

}

$('#calc').click(function() {
  console.log(sum());
});

console.log(sum());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Price: </label>
<span class="itPrice"><b>100</b></span>

<label>Quantity: </label>
<Select id="qty" name="qty" class="qtys">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</Select>

<br>
<br>

<label>Price: </label>
<span class="itPrice"><b>200</b></span>

<label>Quantity: </label>
<Select id="qty" name="qty" class="qtys">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4" selected>4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</Select>

<br>
<br>

<a id="calc" href="javascript:;">Get total</a>
```